# Ajax avatar preview with jQuery In django

Tags: python, html, ajax, django

I've been trying to follow a tutorial. But it doesn't want to work for me. I'm trying to get a simple (or so I thought) avatar preview shown. The problem is that it won't load, or accept the avatar. If I could get another set of eyes on this, and maybe tell me what I'm doing wrong; I'd be very appreciative.

**The template:** (The form is a large overall user information form)

```
<form class="inline" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="/profile/edit/{{ role }}/" id="avatarLoadForm">
     <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/account/settings/">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {% if user_info_form.errors %}{{ user_info_form.errors }}{% endif %}
     <div>
          <label class="form-label" for="id_avatar">Your Picture</label>
          <div id="preview" class="inline-block img-frame thick">   
               <img src="{% if profile.avatar %}{% thumbnail profile.avatar 120x120 crop %}{% else %}{{ DEFAULT_AVATAR }}{% endif %}" id="thumb" alt="" alt="sample-pic" />
          </div>
          {{ user_info_form.avatar }}
     </div>
     <div id="edit-name">
          <label class="form-label" for="id_first_name">Name</label>
          {{ user_info_form.first_name }}
          {{ user_info_form.last_name }}
 ... And so on (other info not relevant)...
```

**The js:**

```
(function() {
        var thumb = $('img#thumb');    
        new AjaxUpload('imageUpload', {
            action: $('#avatarLoadForm').attr('action'),
            name: 'avatar',

            onSubmit: function(file, extension) {
                $("#preview").html('<img id="loader" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');            
            },
            onComplete: function(file, response) {
                thumb.load(function(){
                    $("#preview").html('');
                    thumb.unbind();
                });
                thumb.attr('src', response);
            }
        });
```

**Views.py**

```
@login_required        
def edit_profile(request, profile_type):
    if profile_type == 'investor':
        profile = InvestorProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    elif profile_type == 'manager':
        profile = ManagerProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    context = base_context(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        notify = "You have successfully updated your profile."
        user_info_form = UserInfoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if user_info_form.is_valid():
            user_info_form.save(request.user, profile_type)
            response = simplejson.dumps({"status": "Upload Success"})
        return HttpResponse (response, mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        initial = {}
        initial['first_name'] = request.user.first_name
        initial['last_name'] = request.user.last_name
        initial['email'] = request.user.email
        initial['about'] = profile.about
        initial['country'] = profile.country
        initial['about'] = profile.about
        user_info_form = UserInfoForm(initial=initial)
    context['user_info_form'] = user_info_form
    context['profile_type'] = profile_type
    context['profile'] = profile
    return render_to_response('settings/base.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

***Edit:*** Forms.py:

```
class UserInfoForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-text'}), max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-text'}), max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-text'}))
    about = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'input-text'}), required=False)
    country = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.Select(choices=countries.COUNTRIES))
    avatar = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    #avatar = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'id':'imageUpload'}),required=False)
    investor_type = forms.CharField(max_length=4, widget=forms.Select(choices=choices), required=False)
```

Comment: can you show your forms.py module?

Comment: Check the HTML source of the page. Is the image actually in there? What's the URL of the image? I see you're using thumbnails, it could be that thumbnail generation is going wrong.

Comment: @FrantzdyRomain Added the form (Sorry it took so long, easter happened.)

Comment: Its cool. I suggest taking a look into django-profiles and see how they implement theirs :D

Answer (score 0):

For future reference you should define Avatar as a model with its own fields regardless if it will be a thumbnail. But have you tried

```
 <img src="{% if profile.user %}{% thumbnail avatar 120x120 crop %}{% else %}{{ DEFAULT_AVATAR }}{% endif %}" id="thumb" alt="" alt="sample-pic" />
```